# Get properties passed by user using -DpropertyName=propertyValue

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to get all the properties passed by user while running the application.

`java -Dprop1=val1 -Dprop2=val2 -jar MyApp.jar`

The problem is I do not know the name of the properties which I can use inside 
`System.getProprty(propName)`

When I do

`System.getProperties()`

It returns all properties passed by user along with some other system properties.

Is there any way I can identify which property is passed by user using

`-Dprop=val`

while running the application.

Comment: You can get only commandline arguments you pass in your main methods **args** variable of your spring boot application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode the command line yourself.

```
List<String> inputArguments = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
```

You can then pick out the args which start with `-D`